# show multiple camera perspectives in Google Sketchup

Tags: cinema4d, sketchup

I do a lot of work in both Cinema4D and Google Sketchup, and because of the variety of work I do in both software, I love Cinema4Ds feature of displaying not only just one camera perspective, but 3 or 4 if needed, being locked into different perspectives; Such as is shown in the below image.
[image]

Is there any way I can have the same viewing options in Google Sketchup, via plugin or otherwise? I'm using Google Sketchup 2015. Thanks!

Comment: I've been looking all day and I just don't see it. Kinda lame, perhaps its in the Pro version? What I find is people use Scenes to save angles and then flip back and forth.

Comment: It requires different rendring code to be able to use multi viewports. Most frameworks dont make this super easy.

Comment: It *might* be a pro option. But I'm not sure. AFAIK, this isn't an option at all in the free versions.

Comment: nah, even using a pro version now, i cant find anything. I guess it's no issue, as i have a set of keyboard shortcuts that switch my perspective to these angles. seems to be the next best thing.

Answer (score 1):

In sketchup set the scene or angle you want to view it.
Then Click view > animation > add scene
As soon as u click a tab of scene 1 is shown. You can add as many scene needed[image]

If u have many scene for example 3 scene and you want to go to 2 scene just click on it and it will rotate and show particular scene

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SketchUp's interface simply doesn't support multiple 3D viewpanes in one interface window the way many other 3D DCC tools do (C4D, modo, Maya, 3DS for example) though there is a workaround, assuming a fairly simple model: see this thread in SketchUp Community on this topic ([link](https://forums.sketchup.com/t/multiple-viewport/14984/21)) to see what I mean.

In essence, you declare your model in progress a component, and then place three iterations of your component around the original, each rotated the appropriate amount around the relevant axis; it ends up looking like this as you work:

[image]

To be clear: Cinema 4D, Maya, Modo, 3DS are all serious DCC 3D apps, and have much more complex codebases, toolsets and much more extensible interfaces as well as toolpipes: SketchUp was always designed to be fast, loose, low-rent and not very full-featured - but with a very shallow adoption curve - easy to learn fast. This was the case when SketchUp was first developed by At Last Software, was still true later when it was picked up by Google, and is still true now that it's owned by Trimble.